# add functionality when clicking go back button -ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to count page visits for each page in my ios application . when the number = x I have to show an image. 
I want when clicking back button to count but i don t know where to add this code . Also I can add code in  an init function something like oncreate in android but i see that in ios after passing one time it keeps the page .
thanks, 
raluca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a navigation controller and referring to the back button in the navigation bar then you can use...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)inAnimated
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)inAnimated
```

Which get called when the current view changes.

Comment: though in the way you suggest, the counting would be always done, not only when the back button is pressed...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are aiming at; anyway, if you want to associate an action to the "back" button that is displayed on the navigation bar, you can use:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = TTIMAGE(image);
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer the image i display on whole screen. and if i press back button and it is the 10 time i display the image on all screen .

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear function.